# Android Custom Image Buttons

Tags: android, image, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to implement some custom buttons, they should look something like this:

[image]

So I was wondering if I can use something like a imagebutton and use the image as a background and add text on top of it (I tried this but the text is always in the middle and doesn't have a label so its hard to see..), or should I write a custom style or theme for my button. In case that I have to write a custom style or theme, could you please help me out with this? How should I go about doing it?

Comment: Have you considered simply putting an ImageView and some TextViews inside a RelativeLayout and then just attaching an OnClickListener to the RelativeLayout?

Comment: relative layout will not allow the label to be on top of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of those Grid elements, create a framelayout for each, put the background and then the label in front. Frame layouts allow things on top of each other. You can put the labels with layout_gravity bottom and also add a transparent color to it so the image in the back can be seen. Also add a onClickListener to each of the framelayouts so they act as buttons.

Comment: I created the framelayout, but I need to create the each element programatically, so I thought it would fit in a gridview, in this case how could I make an adapter for this?

Comment: You can have the layout xml for each element defined in each. Use the viewHolder pattern to achieve the dynamically images and labels: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html